# How to implement NUnit's NUnit.Engine.ITestEventListener

Tags: c#, testing, nunit

I would like to use `NUnit.Engine.ITestEventListener` within my test solution. Specifically I would be looking for end of the run <test-run...>.

I implemented the interface `ITestEventListener` within C# code within my test csproj. I set a break point within the interface. Within Visual Studio, I began debugging tests; never hit the break point. I then wondered if this is a NUnit Engine thing and MSTest knows nothing of it. Am I correct that MSTest will never hit my breakpoint with my class that implements ITestEventListener?

Alright lets try something else like writing out to the console log by using `nunit3-console.exe` to run the tests. My output within the interface never wrote a thing - everything else wrote out properly. So, what am I doing incorrectly?

```
using System;
using NUnit.Engine;
using NUnit.Engine.Extensibility;

namespace Learning.NUnitInterface
{
    [Extension]
    public class MyTestListener : ITestEventListener
    {
        public void OnTestEvent(string report)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello there, here is your data: ");
            Console.WriteLine(report);
        }
    }
}
```

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="log4net" Version="2.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.8.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.13.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit.Console" Version="3.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit.ConsoleRunner" Version="3.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit.Engine" Version="3.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.17.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

The NUnit engine is used by the console runner - and other runners - to execute tests. It doesn't refer to the framework at all and the framework doesn't refer to the engine. **In other words**, they are completely separate programs.

Consequently, when you extend the engine, you don't put the extension in your test assembly. You create a separate assembly and build it. Normally, the extension refers to `nunit.engine.api` and no other part of nunit.

After you have built your extension, you need to make it available to the engine. The details of how you do this depend on how you have installed the runner and engine in the first place, that is, whether from the msi package, a nuget package, etc.

Rather than list all the alternative approaches here, I'll leave it at that for now and modify this answer if you post info about how you have installed the console runner.

You can find all the details of how to develop an extension in the NUnit documentation. See https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit-engine/extensions/Index.html

Answer (score 1):

From [NUnit Documentation](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit-engine/extensions/Installing-Extensions.html) you need to use `.addins` file to install an extension:

> `.addins` files are used to locate engine extensions.

And `Console.WriteLine` would probably not work, as it looks to be redirected, for a toy example a logging to a file could be used.

Thanks to @Charlie answer, I managed to make an example of NUnit engine extension for a .net core, as a separate dll, with a project as below:

- MyNunitAddon\MyNunitAddon.csproj

  ```
  <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.13.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit.Engine" Version="3.12.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="MyNunitAddon.addins">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

  </Project>
  ```
- MyNunitAddon\MyNunitAddon.addins

  ```
  MyNunitAddon.dll
  ```
- MyNunitAddon\MyTestListener.cs

  ```
  using System.IO;
  using NUnit.Engine;
  using NUnit.Engine.Extensibility;

  namespace Learning.NUnitInterface
  {
      [Extension]
      public class MyTestListener : ITestEventListener
      {
          private static void WriteToDummyLog(string text)
          {
              File.AppendAllLines("MyTestListener.log", new []{text});
          }

          public void OnTestEvent(string report)
          {
              WriteToDummyLog($"Hello there, here is your data: ");
              WriteToDummyLog(report);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Then a test project referenced to this extension as a project reference:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.9.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.13.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.17.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyNunitAddon\MyNunitAddon.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

After running tests in this project, either via `dotnet test` command line or via Visual Studio 2019, I got MyTestListener.log file populated.

Comment: Note for anyone else following: @Renat's example works for an extension you are building yourself, along with your tests. That can be useful, but it's not the main target for extensions, which are intended to be  distributed. So if anyone gets to the point where you are trying to make a __packaged__ extension using e.g. nuget or chocolatey, please ask another question. :-)

Comment: Where's the [Extension] attribute.  We're on .NET Core 3.1 and the only location suggested is System.runtime.compilerservices which produces a compile error.

Comment: @JWP, [Extension] is `NUnit.Engine.Extensibility.ExtensionAttribute` from `NUnit.Engine` nuget package