# How to wrap a NUnit Engine Extension as a NuGet package?

Tags: nuget, nunit

I am working on a **nunit engine extension** which will be **shipped as a nuget package**.

Following the advises in [How to implement NUnit's NUnit.Engine.ITestEventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66376104/how-to-implement-nunits-nunit-engine-itesteventlistener) i was able to write the extension.

This solution is working as long as the project which contains the extension (the .cs file as well as the .addins file) is being imported to the target project which will perform the nunit tests.

As soon as I create a nuget package (following [Quickstart: Create and publish a NuGet package using Visual Studio (.NET Standard, Windows only)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio?tabs=netcore-cli)) from the extension project and install this package to a test project, the extension doesn't work anymore.

**I assume there is a problem with providing the .addins file within the nuget package** so that the nunit engine in the target project can find the extension.

I already tried to ship the .addins file within the nuget package by adding the following lines to the .csproj file of the extension project.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="file.addins">
    <Pack>true</Pack>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

If I add the .addins file to the target project by hand, the engine extension starts working.

**How can a nunit engine extension be shipped as a nuget package without any adjustments by hand?**

Im using NUnit(3.13.2).

*Im quite new to nunit, nuget and writing questions on stack overflow. So if I'm missing something obvious here, I'm sorry.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of those areas where I wish things were less complicated, unfortunately. Since extensions are found through a relative path from the NUnit engine to the package content, it depends on where both the engine and runner are located and where the package is located on your machine.

Here are some initial guidelines...

1. How to structure the package itself... your extension assembly itself should be in the tools directory. If there are other assemblies with it, which it references, it's best to also include a `.addins` file in the same directory, which lists that assembly on a single line. That way, the NUnit engine will save time by only examining the extension assembly.
2. A NuGet extension package will automatically be found by the engine if the runner has been installed as a nuget package as well. This works no matter how the packages are installed on your machine, i.e. using packages.config or in a nuget cache, *provided both packages were installed the same way*. (That proviso is a real gotcha and it may be that a future version of the engine needs to actually understand nuget.) See the addins file provided with the the NUnit 3 console runner as an example of why this works.
3. The same thing is true if both the runner and the extension are installed as chocolatey packages, because they are both in the chocolatey cache. If you do provide one (which I recomend) it has to be a "native" package - one that includes the actual binaries. A chocolatey package that merely invokes the nuget package will not work. See the source for any of the NUnit-provided extensions for an example of how this this is done.
4. If the executing copy of the engine (usually in the same directory as the runner) is anywhere else, there is no automatic way for the extension to be found. This includes the case where you are building a runner yourself and want the extension to be available while you are developing. In that case, you need to fully understand how the engine finds extensions (see the docs) and manually create an addins file (next to any that was distributed with the engine) containing the proper relative path.

This is especially complicated if you are developing an extension for general release. Then you have to deal with various runners installed in different ways by different people. OTOH, if you are doing this for internal use in your company, you may only need to deal with one of them. If you add more specifics about your goal to the question, I'll edit this with some more specific suggestions.